# OSM Perspective View for Android/iOS

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, elevation, android, ios

I am recently working on a project where i want to show a skiarea in a perspective view, like you know it from maps of skiresorts where the ski lifts are displayed. Are there any libraries where i can achieve this or must i do this by myself?

I want to create something like this, but autogenerated (could be a picture). I want to display it on Android or iOS

[image: Pitztal]

I researched a lot and I think there is not such a thing, but you can prove me wrong, hopefully.

Comment: OSM has information about pistes and their difficulties but lacks the height information needed to generate such a 3D view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is WhirlyGlobe for Android. It's a 3D globe and it allows for tilting to see perspective view.  You can even include Cesium STK Terrain data.   They have their own terrain tool that makes a sqlite database. Elevation Tile Pyramid tool.  http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/

Another option is to embed in a WebView CesiumJS or Terriajs that are WebGL mapping libraries and allow for tiling and seeing terrain relief.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVlrbtRGwgQ  Elevation in WhirlyGlobe
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0wVuFWXadE  Feature Tour